# How to authenticate using warden.authenticate!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I would like to do a 'sign-in or register' on the fly when posting a comment to my forum.  I am using Devise/Warden.

I want to do something like this:

```
user = warden.authenticate!(params[:email], params[:password])
sign_in(:user, user)
```

Can anyone give me some tips on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Warden has a `set_user` helper method. So you should be able to do:

`warden.set_user(@user, scope: :user)`

You could probably define a controller helper method, to sign in the user and redirect them to your desired path

More information is available at: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Authenticated-session-data

Answer (score 1):

Turn on :registerable but not :confirmable in your model.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but I had it worked with

```
# Inside SessionController < Devise::SessionsController
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)  # this will set cookie
end
```

It is devise specific, but when checking auth_options method in devise controller I found this chunk of code [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/SessionsController):

```
# File 'app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb', line 45

def auth_options
    { scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new" }
end
```

Hope that helped.